# ANOVA $\chi^2$ test versus coefficient p-values

Tags: logistic, anova, chi-squared-test, p-value

I try to estimate which of the features I'm using to build my logistic regression model are statistically significant.
Why does the answer given by coefficients p-values differ from the one I receive running anova with the Chisq test on the same model?
Given  significance level equal to 0.05, I would consider significant all of the predictors if the "summary" result is the point of reference,
while only some of them (campaign, emp.var.rate, cons.price.idx, contactCellular, monthNov, monthApr) if the avona result can be considered reliable...
Where's the error I'm making trying to compare these two results.

```
summary(lrModel)

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -136.07498   14.38498  -9.460  < 2e-16 ***
campaign          -0.10364    0.04210  -2.462 0.013818 *  
emp.var.rate      -0.80832    0.06557 -12.328  < 2e-16 ***
cons.price.idx     1.44723    0.15350   9.428  < 2e-16 ***
contactCellular    0.75498    0.21626   3.491 0.000481 ***
monthMay          -2.35165    0.35785  -6.572 4.98e-11 ***
monthJun          -1.87239    0.38341  -4.883 1.04e-06 ***
monthNov          -2.42069    0.40675  -5.951 2.66e-09 ***
monthSep          -1.92832    0.45943  -4.197 2.70e-05 ***
monthJul          -1.96712    0.41211  -4.773 1.81e-06 ***
monthAug          -1.38407    0.39189  -3.532 0.000413 ***
monthOct          -1.86495    0.46663  -3.997 6.43e-05 ***
monthApr          -2.14268    0.39704  -5.397 6.79e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

anova(lrModel, test="Chisq")

                Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                             2855     2003.6              
campaign         1   25.836      2854     1977.8 3.716e-07 ***
emp.var.rate     1  185.153      2853     1792.6 < 2.2e-16 ***
cons.price.idx   1   87.562      2852     1705.0 < 2.2e-16 ***
contactCellular  1   20.015      2851     1685.0 7.685e-06 ***
monthMay         1   15.211      2850     1669.8 9.612e-05 ***
monthJun         1    0.062      2849     1669.8  0.803604    
monthNov         1   10.417      2848     1659.3  0.001248 ** 
monthSep         1    0.666      2847     1658.7  0.414401    
monthJul         1    3.317      2846     1655.4  0.068587 .  
monthAug         1    1.011      2845     1654.3  0.314647    
monthOct         1    0.826      2844     1653.5  0.363428    
monthApr         1   31.622      2843     1621.9 1.873e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: PLEASE NEVER USE ALL CAPITAL LETTERS FOR TITLES. PLEASE EDIT TO CHANGE.

Answer (score 1):

The anova is doing a sequential test. The documentation says
"Specifying a single object gives a sequential analysis of deviance table for that fit. That is, the reductions in the residual deviance as each term of the formula is added in turn are given in as the rows of a table, plus the residual deviances themselves." Notice how the df go down by one each time.